# how may i delete a row from a table by selecting the row in excel without adding too many objects(buttons)?

Tags: excel, vba

im currently trying to improve my actual solution by adding a new one. Summarizing ive a table in excel that creates a delete button for each new row inserted. But if i keep doing like that its going to slow down my file over time cause hundreds of lines are gonna be inserted, consequently alot of objects(buttons). So i need it to be one button that moves around to whichever row is selected by the user.

Thats my currently solution(which isnt the best):

[image]

And thats wat im trying to active:

[image]

Than i ended up stumbled with this code made by https://stackoverflow.com/users/5248324/tomakpo:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)
    set_selected_row Target
End Sub

Sub set_selected_row(ByVal Target As Range)
    Dim tbl As ListObject
    Set tbl = shtList.ListObjects("table3")

    Dim r, c, t
    r = tbl.Range.Rows.Count + 1
    c = tbl.Range.Columns.Count

    If Target.Row < r And Target.Column <= c Then
        Dim btnRemoveItem As Shape
        Set btnRemoveItem = shtList.Shapes("btnRemoveItem")

        t = ((Target.Row - 1) * 15)

        btnRemoveItem.Top = t
    End If
End Sub

Sub remove_item()
    Dim answer As Integer
    answer = MsgBox("Are you sure you want to remove this item?", vbYesNo + vbQuestion, "Remove Item")

    Dim btnRemoveItem As Shape
    Set btnRemoveItem = shtList.Shapes("btnRemoveItem")

    Dim SelectedRow
    SelectedRow = (btnRemoveItem.Top / 15) + 1

    If answer = vbYes Then
        Dim tbl As ListObject
        Set tbl = shtList.ListObjects("table3")

        tbl.ListRows(SelectedRow - 1).Delete

        tr = tbl.Range.Rows.Count
        tc = tbl.Range.Columns.Count

        If SelectedRow > tr Then
            ar = ActiveCell.Row
            ac = ActiveCell.Column

            If ar > tr Or ac > tc Then     'check if the active cell is in the table.
                nr = ar
                nc = ac

                If nr > tr Then nr = tr
                If nc > tc Then nc = tc

                shtList.Cells(nr, nc).Select
                shtList.Cells(ar, ac).Select
            End If
        End If
    End If
End Sub
```

But i cant get it to work with my Actual project (table3 is the name of my table) what else im missing here?( i keeping get the error 424 'Object Required')

See the picture for the depurer error line:

[image]

Comment: Probably, there is no `ListObject` named "table" in `shtList` sheet... Is it a typo and you needed "table3"?

Comment: Sorry the true name is table3 as  u can see in the code above. i miss changed it when taking the picture, but thats not the issue. table3 is the name of the table

Comment: But, you asked about the error... Anyhow, your code is more complicated than it should, I think. Why not moving (directly) the button on the row to be  deleted when pressing the button? Why not creating a variable able to keep the selected cell object and use it when press the button? I will try creating such a code and post it in 2 - 3 minutes...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please, copy the above code in the sheet `shtList` code module. Then, associate `remove_item` sub to the necessary 'button'. It looks to be a shape:

```
Option Explicit

Private actCell As Range
Private Const myTblName As String = "Table3"

Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)
      Dim btnRemoveItem As Shape, tbl As ListObject

      Set tbl = shtList.ListObjects(myTblName)
      If Not Intersect(Target, tbl.DataBodyRange) Is Nothing Then
            Set actCell = Target
            Set btnRemoveItem = shtList.Shapes("btnRemoveItem")
            btnRemoveItem.top = actCell.top
     End If
End Sub

Sub remove_item()
    Dim answer As VbMsgBoxResult, tbl As ListObject
    answer = MsgBox("Are you sure you want to remove this item?", vbYesNo + vbQuestion, "Remove Item")
    If answer <> vbYes Then Exit Sub 'exit if "Yes" not chosen
    
    Set tbl = shtList.ListObjects(myTblName)
    tbl.DataBodyRange.rows(actCell.row - tbl.DataBodyRange.row).Delete
End Sub
```

The necessary button will jump on the row of the table where a cell is selected. If selection is done somewhere else than in the table `DataBodyRange`, nothing will happen in `SelectionChange` event...

Comment: Ok so ive changed the shtList name for my projects name but im still getting error "variable not defined"  on the `Set tbl = myProjectName.ListObjects(myTblName) ` before the  ' tbl.DataBodyRange.rows(actCell.row - tbl.DataBodyRange.row).Delete' line , also ive added the code to ThisWorksheet module

Comment: @jacob d davis This only means that a table named as `myTblName` does not exist in sheet `myProjectName`. Is `myProjectName` the sheet code name, or its name?

Comment: @jacob d davis So, do you still receive that error, or not? I can see you edited the comment and do not mention it, anymore. Does the code work as you need?

Comment: Yes, im getting a different error now. myProjectname is the Files name which im actually have 4 sheets included. Also ive added the code to 'ThisWorkbook' on excel VBA tab. which im not sure if thats supposed to be like that.(im dumb)

Comment: This is how i setted up the things i putted the first half of the code in the MyWorkBook and the remove_item inside a module as  showed in the picture 'https://ibb.co/0cY8rHf'

Comment: @jacob d davis I am afraid you do not understand too much about Excel objects... 1. You need to declare/have **a sheet** in side the workbook you need processing, where a table named as `myTblName` must exist. 2. I told you **copy the above code in the sheet `shtList` code module**. You should copy the code in the `shtList`, or its equivalent **code module** (right click on the sheet name and choose `View Code`... The code should not be placed in `ThisWorkbook` module. 3. I said to copy all code there, to not need other modifications. If you understand VBA, you can place it in a module...

Comment: @jacob d davis But, in such a case, `actCell ` must be declared as `Public` and the constant has to also be declared on top of the used standard module, or at the `Sub` level. Anyhow, can you explain why didn't you proceed **exactly as I suggested**? Then, **why did you change the workbook/sheet, whatever and you din not test it on the sheet you show us**, because the code was set to work on that environment? You always must test the code as it is, on the environment presented in the question. Only after seeing it working you try modifying it. In this way, at least, you know that it works...

Comment: Thanks for ur time , i finally managed to get it for work, sorry for the headache, im still trying to learn VBA and thats my first Project. i appreciate the help. and youre right i didnt proceeded as u suggested, also i would like to apologize for my inexperience and I tried doing it with a shape button and it doesnt work. but it worked with an activeX  command button.

Answer (score 0):

I think FaneDuru is right regarding the reason for your 424-error.

But I would like to suggest you a less complex solution.
You don't need shapes (that slow down everything) - instead you can use hyperlinks.

You add a hyperlink per cell with this code (placed in a normal module - and called whenever you need it):

```vb
Public Sub writeDeleteButtons(rg As Range)
Dim c As Range
For Each c In rg.Cells
    c.Hyperlinks.Add c, vbNullString, , , "delete"
Next
End Sub
```

This could look like this:
[image]

In your worksheets-module you have the following event which is triggered whenever a hyperlink is clicked. `Target.Range` returns the cell that was clicked.

```vb
Private Sub Worksheet_FollowHyperlink(ByVal Target As Hyperlink)

If Target.Range.Value = "add" Then
    'addRow Me   'propably you want to implement the same for adding a row
ElseIf Target.Range = "delete" Then
    deleteRow Me, Target.Range.row
End If

End Sub
```

And finally you have your routine to delete the row through a sub that is again placed in a normal module:

```vb
Public Sub deleteRow(ws As Worksheet, rowIndex As Long)
If vbNo = MsgBox("Are you sure you want to remove this item?", vbYesNo + vbQuestion, "Remove Item") Then
    Exit Sub
End If

ws.Rows(rowIndex).Delete
End Sub
```

You could adjust `deleteRows` to pass the clicked cell itself and go on from there.

A completely different solution would be to have a custom ui context menu ... but this would need a lot more explanations ...